# How to get Jenkins and Perforce to ignore files accessed through symlink?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have the following problem on my Jenkins with Perforce setup:
The original branch content like described below, because all 3 modules are needed to build product. So a build workspace would contain all 3 modules.

```
//depot-product/moduleA
               /moduleB
               /moduleC
```

I've created a mapping to look only any changes on moduleA. So my mapping looks like this:

```
//depot-product/moduleA/... //workspace/moduleA/...
```

However, what I didn't expect is that on moduleA's code there are symlinks to directories on other modules. So p4 fails with this message below:

```
Caught exception communicating with perforce. Errors encountered while force syncing: error: open for write: /home/user/jenkins/jobs/jobModuleA/workspace/moduleA/dir1/symDir/file.txt: No such file or directory
```

symDir is a link to a file on moduleB.

So my question is, can I tell p4 sync to ignore the files that are outside this worskpace, or directories pointed to by symlinks ?

Comment: Are these files of type "symlink" that have been stored in Perforce? Or symbolic links that were created on your workstation, not by using Perforce?

Comment: Got my answer. Just need to do the following:
- Include moduleB on my mapping.
- On the Avanced section on 'Source Code Management', go to the "Poll Exclude File(s)" block and insert '//depot-product/moduleB' so as to tell jenkins not to monitor the changes there.

Comment: @BryanPendleton. The symlinks had been stored on Perforce.